# static stack function does not 1) take input of 1st element 2)recognise old element when new element is added

Tags: c++, arrays, stack

There is an array of nodes(a structure) and is used as a 
stack.
it has 3 functions

- to add new elements (push)
- to delete elements(pop)
- to display(display)

problems:

1. does not save the first input
2. when a new input is added, it replaces the previous node with the new input.

please help me identify where i have gone wrong

```
#include <iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<process.h>

struct node
{
    int x, y;
};
int top = -1;
class stack
{
    node s[30];
public:
    void push();
    void pop();
    void display();
};
void stack::push()
{
    if (top < 29)
    {
        cout << "enter elements" << endl;
        int a, b;
        cin >> a >> b;
        top = top + 1;
        s[top].x = a;
        s[top].y = b;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "OVERFLOW" << endl;
    }
}

void stack::pop()
{
    node temp;
    temp = s[top];
    top--;
    cout << "element" << temp.x << "&" << temp.y << " has been deleted" << endl;
}

void stack::display()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < top; i++)
    {
        cout << s[top].x << "&" << s[top].y << endl;
    }
}
void main()
{
    clrscr();
    stack sup;
     int choice = 1;
    do
    {
        cout << "1.add" << endl << "2.delete" << endl << "3.display" << endl;
        int c;
        cin >> c;
        switch (c)
        {
            case 1:
                sup.push();
                sup.display();
                break;
            case 2:
                sup.pop();
                sup.display();
                break;
            case 3:
                sup.display();
                break;
            default:
                cout << "error in switch case" << endl;
        }
        cout << "enter 1 to perform more operations" << endl;
        cin >> choice;
    } while (choice == 1);
    getch();
}
```

Comment: Note `push` should place an element into the stack and do nothing more. if you remove the IO from `push` you may find this easier to debug.

Comment: Unrelated: `top` as a global variable means you can only ever have one `stack`. I recommend making it a member variable.

Comment: Unrelated: `if (top < 29)` will give you an off-by-one bug.

Comment: I didnt find anything `static` in the code. What do you refer to?

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818  static refers to the fact that the stack is an array of a fixed size. dynamic is where we can keep creating new spaces for elements as required.

Comment: @user4581301  since top starts  storing values from 0 , I set max limit for top to be incremented upto 29. 0-29 gives 30 elements (the array size is 30).

Comment: I stand corrected. Suggestion: Start `top` at 0 rather than -1 and increment `top` after adding an item rather than before. The more predictable and less complicated you make things, the easier it is to debug.

Answer (score 1):

You delete and recreate you stack (`sup`) every iteration of your loop.  The declaration should be before the `do`.

Comment: Now, I declared (sup) before the do-while, yet the the problems still occur

Comment: Never underestimate how many bugs there can be in a program. Ask a new question with updated code and preferably a [mcve].